# Why apollo client:codegen is not generate types?

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client, codegen

im trying to get the types defined in my Apollo server

by first, downloading the schema effectively:

```
apollo client:download-schema src/code/queries/schemas/schema.json --endpoint http://localhost:4000/
```

that command generates the following .json, reduced it for demonstration purposes.

```
{
"__schema": {
"queryType": {
  "name": "Query"
},
"mutationType": {
  "name": "Mutation"
},
"subscriptionType": null,
"types": [
  {
    "kind": "OBJECT",
    "name": "Query",
    "description": null,
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "UserInformation",
        "description": null,
        "args": [],
        "type": {
          "kind": "OBJECT",
          "name": "User",
          "ofType": null
        },
        "isDeprecated": false,
        "deprecationReason": null
      }
    ],
    "inputFields": null,
    "interfaces": [],
    "enumValues": null,
    "possibleTypes": null
  },
  {
    "kind": "OBJECT",
    "name": "User",
    "description": null,
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "firstName",
        "description": null,
        "args": [],
        "type": {
          "kind": "SCALAR",
          "name": "String",
          "ofType": null
        },
        "isDeprecated": false,
        "deprecationReason": null
      },
      {
        "name": "secondName",
        "description": null,
        "args": [],
        "type": {
          "kind": "SCALAR",
          "name": "String",
          "ofType": null..........
```

then tying to generate the types as typescript without success:

```
   apollo client:codegen --target typescript --localSchemaFile src/code/queries/schemas/schema.json  --outputFlat src/code/queries/generated
```

the globalTypes.ts is generated empty (only comments)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `--includes` option to indicate which files contain the actual queries for which to generate the types. From the [docs](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output):

> **--includes=includes** Glob of files to search for GraphQL operations. This should be used to find queries *and* any client schema extensions